# Vue push object into array and make immutable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm pretty new to Vue/Javascript so this is probably a super simple answer. I have a component that opens a modal where you can choose a product to add to order. The problem is that I when I modify the price then re-open the modal that all the prices are reset.

How can the `pickProduct` function be modified so that the changes persist when re-opening the modal?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/bdoubleu/pen/dyPLLva?editors=1011)

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    orderForm: {
      lines: []
    },
    defaultLine: {
      product: null,
      price: ''
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    pickProduct(product) {
      const emptyLine = Object.assign({}, this.defaultLine)
      const newProduct = Object.assign({}, product)
      Object.assign(emptyLine, newProduct)
      newProduct.product = newProduct.id

      // this.orderForm.lines.push(newProduct)
      this.orderForm.lines = [...this.orderForm.lines, newProduct]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: You could save the data to your store using [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) to handle managing your state of the modal. When the modal is opened, it accesses that variable of your application state, and updates it as needed.

Comment: if you are using es6 syntax, then you may consider 
`const newProduct = {...this.defaultLine, ...product}`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking, but you could make the object immutable by using [.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) method

Comment: @EmīlsGulbis is that just a suggestion? Unfortunately the outcome is the same

Comment: Just suggestion for cleaner code, since @EvanBechtol give you already the best advice for this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `:value` in your price input, that doesn't actually change the value for the object you are editing. So this has nothing to do immutability. To actually bind the value for the object, use `v-model` instead of value.

So change this:

```
<input type="text" :value="item.price" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" v-model="item.price" />
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/yLyrdQO?editable=true&editors=101)**